# htaccess 301 redirection with 500 error with "?" in URL

Tags: .htaccess, 301-redirect

I'm trying to redirect some URLs internally.

From:

```
https://example.com/?cat=123
```

To

```
https://example.com/?cat=456
```

In `.htaccess` file I wrote:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^?cat=123$ https://example.com/?cat=456 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But this causes 500 server error, and with some trial and error, I found this is caused by `?` character in `?cat=123`.

If I remove `?`, 500 error will be gone although redirection doesn't work.

Also, as long as there is no `?` in the old URL redirection works fine.

This works fine:

```
RewriteRule ^cat=123$ https://example.com/?cat=456 [R=301,L]
```

This indicate `?` in new URL doesn't cause the problem.

It seems that in `.htaccess` file has problem recognizing `?` character.

Does anyone know how to solve or avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the `?` in the URL. The problem is the regex you are trying to use...

> `^?cat=123$`

This regex is not valid - the cause of the 500 internal server error (the error log would have reported that the regular expression could not be compiled - or words to that effect). This isn't particular to `.htaccess` - any regular expression parser would have thrown the same error.

The `?` is a special meta character in a regex that makes the previous item optional. But `^` is not quantifiable and therefore cannot be "optional".

However, there is something more fundamentally wrong with how you are trying to do this. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, this notably excludes the query string (as denoted by `?` in the URL). So, trying to match the query string in the `RewriteRule` directive will never work.

In order to match the query string, ie. everything after the first `?`, you need a `RewriteCond` directive that matches against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

For example, to redirect from `https://example.com/?cat=123` to `https://example.com/?cat=456`, you would need to do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=123$
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/?cat=456 [R=302,L]
```

The `?` does not appear as part of the `QUERY_STRING` (or URL-path) value.

If you specifically need to match the hostname then you'll need another `RewriteCond` directive that matches against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable. If you have already canonicalised the scheme+hostname and you only have one domain then you can remove the scheme+hostname from the `RewriteRule` *substitution*.

Change the 302 (temporary) redirect to 301 (permanent) only once you have confirmed this works as intended. 301s are cached persistently by the browser, so can make testing problematic.

I assume you must have had a `RewriteEngine` directive already in your code. There is no need for the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper, unless you are porting these directives to multiple servers where mod_rewrite might not be installed and this redirect is *optional*?

> as long as there is no `?` in the old URL redirection works fine.

In this case, there is no query string, only a URL-path and everything will be matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.